# Why is a switch case statement unable to work with properties of an Enum?

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

I am writing a simple game in which I use an Enum, `CommandManager`, to store information about the possible commands and what each one does. The main purposes of this Enum is to be able to print out a menu of available commands, as well as being used to check input and performing the action related to that input. My problem lies with that second use, where I am using a switch statement to determine what the user wants to do based on their input. I'm getting a compilation error when trying to use a property of an Enum (via a getter method) as a case label. The error message provided is that `case expressions must be constant expressions`. Given that the properties of `CommandManager` are declared to be final, am I right in thinking that properties of Enums simply cannot be used in switch statements? If this is the case, why?

Simplified version of the code included below in case it's an error on my end.

Method Code:

```
void interpretInput()   {
    String command = input.getInput();
    if (command.length() == 2)  {
            switch (command) {
            case CommandManager.MAINMENU.getCommand(): goToMainMenu(); 
                    break;
            case CommandManager.NEWGAME.getCommand(): startNewGame();
                    break;
            case CommandManager.LISTGAMES.getCommand(): listSavedGames();
                    break;
            case CommandManager.EXITGAME.getCommand(): exitGame();
                    break;
            case CommandManager.HELPMENU.getCommand(): listAllCommands();
                    break;
            }
    }
}
```

Enum code:

```
public enum CommandManager {

NEWGAME("!n", "New game"),
MAINMENU("!m", "Go to main menu"),
EXITGAME("!q", "Exit Battleships"),
LISTGAMES("!g", "List saved games"),
HELPMENU("!h", "Open help menu"),
LOADGAME("!l", "Load a new game"),
SAVEGAME("!s", "Save current game");

private final String command;
private final String menuOption;

CommandManager(String aCommand, String anOption)    {
    command = aCommand;
    menuOption = anOption;
}

String getCommand() {
    return command;
}

String getMenuOption()  {
    return menuOption;
}
}
```

Comment: Because they are not compile time constant.

Comment: You can use Enums in switch statements, but you are not. You are using String, but as the error message says, the labels have to be constants.

Comment: After reading `String command` from input, it would be nice to get the according enum value and then switch on the enum directly.

Comment: You aren't putting the `enum` to good use if you're switching against String values. If that's your goal, the have a number of `public static final String` constants. You'll be able to switch against them.

Comment: If you are authoring the `enum` class, then it's usually a mistake to `switch` on it because you can write constant-specific methods for the enum constants that in nearly every case provide a more object-oriented, robust, and more easily maintainable solution.  Actually, in nearly every case your first reflex after writing `switch` in your code should be to ask yourself "is there a way in which I can -not- switch?"

Comment: @scottb Not if there are many heterogeneous `switch` statements around the code. You get clutter in the `enum`; you're displacing the logic into another file; you can't access local variables.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: can't agree.  Heterogenous switches scattered around code may be the very best time to use constant-specific methods because all the logic gets centralized with the constants that use it and can greatly improve the maintainability of the code, especially if an enum constant is added.

Comment: @scottb It also fails at extensibility: you can't add more use sites without modifying the enum. And you didn't provide any solution for lacking access to local variables, including `this`, and enclosing instances. You don't have access to private methods accessible in the context. You might also need to change several local variables, so one return value is not enough. You might even have flow-control statements: another no-go for enum methods.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Extensibility is an issue with enums generally (because they can't be extended) and not constant-specific methods in particular (interface inheritance can be used to provide a kind of extensible enum at the cost of some added complexity).  I maintain, however, that switching on enums is much less robust.  With constant specific methods, keeping your code up to date when a constant is added is enforced by the compiler.  With `switch`, the common failure is to forget to update all your `switch`s.

Comment: @scottb The main advantage of `switch`ing against an enum is that the compiler can warn you about missing cases, and will do so if asked. About extensibility, you seem to be conflating all kinds of meanings of the word. The only meaning I used was "adding more constant-specific behavior without modifying the enum class". Interface inheritance will not help.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Personally, I don't see "adding more constant-specific behavior" to an enum as a problem.  In my view, a rich enum type has its own API which is specified in the fields and methods of each constant.  Having the code that expresses this API within the enum 1) keeps all the enum API code together with the constants, and 2) makes the client code simpler and cleaner.   All that I can add at this point is to say that every time I've written constant-specific methods rather than `switch`s, I've been happy that I did even for very rich enum types.

Comment: @scottb I enumerated a cornucopia of use cases where it starts hurting to use enum methods. They support the main point that "use enum methods" cannot be general advice for all situations. All of that put together still doesn't _deny_ the existence of use cases where enum methods are the right choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a bit different approach. You can write a static method inside your enum to convert command string into CommandManager enum:

```
public static CommandManager fromCommand(String command) {
    for (CommandManager commandManager : values()) {
        if (commandManager.getCommand().equals(command)) {
            return commandManager;
        }
    }
    return null; // or throw exception, whatever fits best for your code
}
```

Then you can invoke this method to get en enum object and use a switch statement to do whatever you want:

```
String command = input.getInput();
CommandManager commandManager = CommandManager.fromCommand(command);
if (commandManager != null)  {
    switch (commandManager) {
        case MAINMENU: 
            goToMainMenu();
            break;
        case NEWGAME: 
            startNewGame();
            break;
        case LISTGAMES: 
            listSavedGames();
            break;
        case EXITGAME: 
            exitGame();
            break;
        case HELPMENU: 
            listAllCommands();
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown command: " + commandManager);
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer, and @HovercraftFullOfEels answer, made sense to me and solved my problem so I'm marking this as the resolution. Thanks for your help, and to everyone else who contributed answers - lots of interesting stuff for me to read into.

Answer (score 5):

> Am I right in thinking that properties of Enums simply cannot be used in switch statements?

You are.

> If this is the case, why?

Because the "labels" for a switch statement need to be *compile time* constants, and the properties of an `enum` do not qualify.

The reason that they need to be compile time constants is that the compiler needs to check that the switch labels are distinct.  It cannot allow something like this

```
switch (someValue) {
    case A.method():  doA();
    case B.method():  doB();
}
```

where `A.method()` and `B.method()` turn out to have the same value.  If the case expressions are not compile-time constant expressions, then the compiler cannot detect the problem.  (Method calls are never compile time constant expressions.)

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation as to why I was getting the error.

Answer (score 2):

I would do things differently by using a Map to help with an action design pattern.

First add to your CommandManager enum a method that converts a command String to a CommandManager object, something like:

```
public static CommandManager getCommandManager(String command) {
    for (CommandManager cManager : CommandManager.values()) {
        if (command.equals(cManager.getCommand())) {
            return cManager;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(command);
}
```

e.g.,

```
public enum CommandManager {

    NEWGAME("!n", "New game"), 
    MAINMENU("!m", "Go to main menu"), 
    EXITGAME("!q", "Exit Battleships"), 
    LISTGAMES("!g", "List saved games"), 
    HELPMENU("!h", "Open help menu"), 
    LOADGAME("!l", "Load a new game"), 
    SAVEGAME("!s", "Save current game");

    private final String command;
    private final String menuOption;

    CommandManager(String aCommand, String anOption) {
        command = aCommand;
        menuOption = anOption;
    }

    String getCommand() {
        return command;
    }

    String getMenuOption() {
        return menuOption;
    }

    // ************ ADD THIS! *******
    public static CommandManager getCommandManager(String command) {
        for (CommandManager cManager : CommandManager.values()) {
            if (command.equals(cManager.getCommand())) {
                return cManager;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(command);
    }
}
```

Then give your code that uses this a Map that maps each CommandManager with a Runnable, and fill the map:

```
public class TestEnum {
    private Map<CommandManager, Runnable> commandMap = new EnumMap<>(CommandManager.class);

    public TestEnum() {
        commandMap.put(CommandManager.MAINMENU, () -> goToMainMenu());
        commandMap.put(CommandManager.MAINMENU, () -> goToMainMenu());
        commandMap.put(CommandManager.NEWGAME, () -> startNewGame());
        commandMap.put(CommandManager.LISTGAMES, () -> listSavedGames());
        commandMap.put(CommandManager.EXITGAME, () -> exitGame());
        commandMap.put(CommandManager.HELPMENU, () -> listAllCommands());
    }
```

Then use it!

```
void interpretInput(String command) {
    CommandManager cManager = CommandManager.getCommandManager(command);
    commandMap.get(cManager).run();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply "CommandManager.MAINMENU.getCommand()" is not a Constant, is a function.
Element in enum is Constant, so you have to convert String to enum element.

I used a map to store relation between command and enum element:

```
public enum CommandManager {

  NEWGAME("!n", "New game"),
  MAINMENU("!m", "Go to main menu"),
  EXITGAME("!q", "Exit Battleships"),
  LISTGAMES("!g", "List saved games"),
  HELPMENU("!h", "Open help menu"),
  LOADGAME("!l", "Load a new game"),
  SAVEGAME("!s", "Save current game");

  private final String command;
  private final String menuOption;
  private static class InnerClass {
    static Map<String, CommandManager> commandMap = new HashMap<>();
  }

  CommandManager(String aCommand, String anOption)    {
    command = aCommand;
    menuOption = anOption;
    InnerClass.commandMap.put(aCommand, this);
  }

  public static CommandManager parseCommand(String aCommand) {
    return InnerClass.commandMap.get(aCommand);
  }

  String getCommand() {
    return command;
  }

  String getMenuOption()  {
    return menuOption;
  }
}
```

Then change the switch code

```
public void interpretInput()   {
  String command = input.getInput();
  if (command.length() == 2)  {
    CommandManager commandManager = CommandManager.parseCommand(command);
    if (commandManager!=null) {
      switch (commandManager) {
        case MAINMENU: goToMainMenu();
          break;
        case NEWGAME: startNewGame();
          break;
        case LISTGAMES: listSavedGames();
          break;
        case EXITGAME: exitGame();
          break;
        case HELPMENU: listAllCommands();
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```